# When inserting data from Android to MySQL, why is all the data inserted with the number "1"?

Tags: php, android, mysql

When inserting data from Android to MySQL, why is all the data inserted with the number "1"?
When I insert it directly from the console, it inserts normally. What's the problem?

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lice");
    mysqli_query($con, 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
    
    $name = isset($_POST["name"]);

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO USER(NAME) VALUES (?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $name); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

This is part of Activity code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                name = uname.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

                            if(success){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name + "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                };

                UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest(name, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue( UserActivity.this );
                queue.add(userRequest);
            }
        });
```

This is Request code:

```
public class UserRequest extends StringRequest {
    final static private String URL = "my url";
    private Map<String, String> parameters;

    public UserRequest(String name, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, URL, listener, null);
        parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("name", name);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot insert anything to `phpMyAdmin` because its a tool written in PHP, do you mean MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I mean MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the value you're inserting:

```
$name = isset($_POST["name"]);
```

Per the documentation, `isset` [returns a `bool`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).  So you're not inserting a "name", you're inserting "whether or not the name was provided".

Instead, insert the "name":

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` returns a boolean ,  true or false, which can equate to 1 or ''

so

```
$name = isset($_POST["name"]);
```

will set `$name` to 1 or ''

Instead try

```
$name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : '';
```

which checks that the value is set and if so moves it to the `$name` var otherwise it set it to  `''`

Which probably means you should do a bit more checking before using it in a query like

```
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "lice");
    mysqli_query($con, 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO USER(NAME) VALUES (?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $_POST["name"]); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'Missing name';
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: a boolean is not 1 or 0. It's true or false. If you cast it to a string like OP did then it will be either "1" or ""

Comment: Also, `isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : '';` is a very long way of just writing `$_POST["name"] ?? '';`